# Regex to parse C++ function return type (for a practical subset of C++)

Tags: .net, regex

Consider a declaration like this:

```
virtual Foo * const operator=(Bar& b);
```

or

```
virtual Foo * const operator=   (Bar& b); // note the optional number of whitespace after the function name
```

I want to capture the `Foo * const` part. In other words, I would like to match all characters between the start of the string, an optional virtual|static and an opening brace, except for the last word and an optional amount of whitespace before the brace.

I came up with the following:

```
(?virtual|static)?\s*(?.*?)(?!\s*\()
```

But this does not work.

Edit.: some more examples:

```
Input                             Capture
-----                             -------
void f();                         void
static int Foo();                 int
virtual const int * const         const int * const
virtual Foo * operator+(Foo& b);  Foo *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure what you are looking for, but if I got it right, this is probably what you are looking for:

```
^(?:virtual|static)?\s*(.*?)(?=\s\w+=)
```

And tested on [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/eQ3xB8).

The lookahead is not necessary though:

```
^(?:virtual|static)?\s*(.*?)\s\w+=
```

Otherwise, if you want to get the whole `Foo * const operator=   (` part, maybe this?

```
^(?:virtual|static)?\s*(.*?)\(
```

I feel like you don't understand the negative lookahead or non-capturing group well.

`(?:...)` is a non capturing group (notice the colons).

`(?!...)` is a negative lookahead, which prevents matching of a character being followed by what's in the group. You would rather prefer a positive lookahead in your case to capture everything *before* that bracket, but it's not necessary in this particular case since a simple `.*\(` will suffice.

EDIT: Subject to new test samples, a bit more complicated regex:

```
^(?:virtual|static)?\s*(.+?)(?:(?:\s*\w+[\(=\+\?\!])|$)
```

Comment: There isn't necessarily an `=` character at the end of the function name, I just chose one to indicate that there might be. A close enough pattern to match the function name would be `[_a-zA-z]\w+[=\?\+\!]*` but simply replacing the part between `\s*` and `\(` does not work.

Comment: @fish Could you perhaps supply more possible inputs and say what you want to get exactly as output in your question?

Comment: Sure, I have provided more examples.

Comment: That's great, thank you for the effort. You even managed to match my mistaken second example (where I meant to add a function name like in the other cases) :)